# How to show or hide the Quick Access Toolbar in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

How do I show or hide the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) in Word with VBA?

With `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MinimizeRibbon")` I can hide the whole ribbon but not only the QAT.

Is there an idMso for the QAT?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/50564-how-show-hide-qat-quick-access-toolbar.html. For cross-posting etiquette please see https://excelguru.ca/a-message-to-forum-cross-posters/

Comment: Use [Custom UI Editor](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor-download.htm)

Comment: Read this too: [Show or hide the Quick Access Toolbar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52#bkmk_show_hide_qat)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following ribbon XML to hide all QAT items:

```
...
<qat>
  <sharedControls>
    <button idMso="QuckAccessToolbarCustomization" visible="false" />
  </sharedControls>
</qat>
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!

The a problem i have with a custom QAT, it's with startFromScratch="true" which hides all other tabs (except the custom ribbon). 
Is there a solution?

Sincerely, David

Comment: Nope. There is no trivial way for hiding the QAT only. A possible solution is described in my post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!

Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",false)" is for excel if I'm not mistaken and not for word.

Comment: Yes, the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method exists in Excel only.